# FOSUserBundle: Custom password / Migration from old DB structure

Tags: passwords, symfony, md5, database-migration, fosuserbundle

I want to move to Symfony2, because I am totally impressed by its modernity and good programming.

Now I am taking a users table from my old system, with 10,000 users, and I don't want to anger them by making them set a new password....so I want them to be able to login with their old password

Here is pseudo-code of how my users table looks like with 3 major fields concerning login/signup:

```
id, int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
username varchar(40) NOT NULL
passhash varchar(32) NOT NULL
secret varchar(20) NOT NULL
```

on **signup**, the data gets generated this way:

```
$secret = mksecret ();
$passhash = md5 ($secret . $password_formfield . $secret);
```

on **login**, the data gets checked the following way:

```
if ($row['passhash'] != md5 ($row['secret'] . $password_formfield . $row['secret']))
{
//show login error
}
```

So how do I handle it best in FOSUserBundle, without having to edit too many files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to create a custom password encoder:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\BasePasswordEncoder;

class MyPasswordEncoder extends BasePasswordEncoder
{
    public function encodePassword($raw, $salt)
    {
        return md5($salt.$raw.$salt);
    }

    public function isPasswordValid($encoded, $raw, $salt)
    {
        return $this->comparePasswords($encoded, $this->encodePassword($raw, $salt));
    }
}
```

And configure it in `security.yml`:

```
services:
    my_password_encoder:
        class: MyPasswordEncoder

security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: { id: my_password_encoder }
```

As long as `User::getSalt()` returns `secret` and `User::getPassword()` returns `passhash` you should be good to go.

Comment: thanks Kris , very well explained. But where do i paste my password encoder?

Comment: You can put that class in one of your bundles.

Comment: aight, will put it under Security\Encoder\MyPasswordEncoder.php

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to do with FOSUserBundle. This is the code for it:

```
$userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $newItem = $userManager->createUser();

    //$newItem->setId($item->getObjId());
    // FOSUserBundle required fields
    $newItem->setUsername($item->getUsername());
    $newItem->setEmail($item->getEmail());
    $newItem->setPlainPassword($item->getPassword()); // get original password
    $newItem->setEnabled(true);

    $userManager->updateUser($newItem, true);
}
```

Comment: You set it using `plainPassword` field, and it will be encoded by FOSUserBundle or your own security encoder.

Comment: This will work only if you start with a plain text password.
If you start with an encoded password, you will have a double encoding.