# Custom Symfony FOSUserBundle service for migrating legacy passwords

Tags: passwords, fosuserbundle, symfony

I am trying to plug in my own legacy password service into Symfony3 to passively migrate users from a legacy database table.

The legacy system has passwords hashe with the same hard-coded `$salt` variables used across all members (therefore my FOSUserBundle table currently has the salt column empty for all members that are to be migrated).

The legacy method uses:

```
sha1($salt1.$password.$salt2)
```

The new method is Symfony's FOSUserBundle standard bcrypt hash.

I am trying to implement it so that when a legacy user first logs in, Symfony will try to:

1. Log in using FOSUserBundle's standard bcrypt method.
2. If #1 did not succeed then try the legacy algorithm.
3. If #2 succeeeds the password hash and salt in the database table will be updated to comply with standard FOSUserBundle method

I have been reading around about how to plug in a service to get this working and I think the below that I have seems to be correct in theory - if not any corrections/guidance would be appreciated as I've not been able to test it!

**However, I'm unsure how I should go about connecting it all into Symfony so that the normal FOSUserBundle processes will carry out steps 2 and 3 if step 1 fails**

**services.yml:**

```
parameters:
    custom-password-encoder:
        class: AppBundle\Security\LegacyPasswordEncoder
```

**security.yml:**

```
security:
    encoders:
        #FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt       Commented out to try the following alternative to give password migrating log in
         FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: { id: custom-password-encoder }
```

**BCryptPasswordEncoder (standard FOSUserBundle):**

```
class BCryptPasswordEncoder extends BasePasswordEncoder
{
    /* .... */

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function encodePassword($raw, $salt)
    {
        if ($this->isPasswordTooLong($raw)) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException('Invalid password.');
        }

        $options = array('cost' => $this->cost);

        if ($salt) {
            // Ignore $salt, the auto-generated one is always the best
        }

        return password_hash($raw, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isPasswordValid($encoded, $raw, $salt)
    {
        return !$this->isPasswordTooLong($raw) && password_verify($raw, $encoded);
    }
}
```

**LegacyPasswordEncoder:**

```
namespace AppBundle\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\BasePasswordEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException;

class LegacyPasswordEncoder extends BasePasswordEncoder
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function encodePassword($raw,$salt)
    {
        if ($this->isPasswordTooLong($raw)) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException('Invalid password.');
        }

        list($salt1,$salt2) = explode(",",$salt);
        return sha1($salt1.$raw.$salt2);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isPasswordValid($encoded, $raw, $salt)
    {
        list($salt1,$salt2) = explode(",",$salt);
        return !$this->isPasswordTooLong($raw) && $this->comparePasswords($encoded,sha1($salt1.$raw.$salt2));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by mapping your user class to the desired encoder:

```
security:
  hide_user_not_found: false
  encoders:
    Cerad\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User: # Replace with your user class
        id: cerad_user.user_encoder # Replace with the service id for your encoder
```

That should be enough to get your encoder plugged in.

Then you need to actually write your custom encoder by extending BCryptPasswordEncoder and override the isPasswordValid method.  And of course create a service for it.  Lots to learn.

How to call BcryptPasswordEncorder followed by LegacyPasswordEncoder?  You don't.  At least not directly.  Symfony does not have a chain password encoder.  Instead, write your own encoder and implement the chaining yourself.

```
class MyEncoder extends BCryptPasswordEncoder
{
  function isPasswordValid($encoded,$raw,$salt)
  {
    // Check the bcrypt
    if (parent::isPasswordValid($encoded,$raw,$salt)) return true;

    // Copied from legacy
    list($salt1,$salt2) = explode(",",$salt);
    return 
      !$this->isPasswordTooLong($raw) &&
       $this>comparePasswords($encoded,sha1($salt1.$raw.$salt2));
```

And make sure you define your encoder under services and not parameter.  Also be sure to pass the cost (default is 13) as a constructor argument.

Comment: Thanks Cerad - although just so I'm clear, isn't this `security:` section you mentioned the same as what I have in my question already under `security.yml`? My attempt at the custom encoder is `LegacyPasswordEncoder` in my question (I will update it to extend `BCrptPasswordEncoder` this evening) which contains my attempt at the custom `isPasswordValid` method you mentioned too. Is this wrong?

Comment: Update your question with the encoders section of your security file.  All I am currently seeing is a parameter.  The encoder section is how you map a particular user entity class to an actual encoder.  Here is another explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771655/fosuserbundle-custom-password-migration-from-old-db-structure.

Comment: Sorry about that - I copied over the wrong section(!). I've updated my question with the `encoder:` section. I think I'm getting confused about how both `BCryptPasswordEncoder` would first check if the password is valid and if not then call `LegacyPasswordEncoder`

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is to use the Symfony feature allowing to change the password hashing algorithm dynamically based on the user: https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/named_encoders.html

This way, you can mark any non-migrated user as using a legacy algorithm. Then, when updating the password, you would reset the algorithm being used before saving the user, so that the new password is hashed using the new stronger algorithm